# Typo3 FE not working after moving to different server (500)

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

After moving a clients Typo3 Website to a different server (same domain), Frontend only shows 500 error.
Backend works fine, and there are no errors in install tool.
I cleared all caches.

My error log just says

```
[XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX] https://XXX.XX/ - flux: Built content setup for page 1
[XXXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX] https://XXX.XX/ - flux: Built content setup for page 68
```

every minute, like some sort of cron job?

Doesn't look like a error though.
Any ideas what that could be and why its not working?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that `RewriteBase /` was not set in `.htaccess`....